# SoaSuiteComposites Delete old versions

Tags: oracle-soa

I am facing a challenge with deleting old composite versions in SoaSuite. I had a composite that uses local File Adapters to read files from and write to different folders. I had encountered some problems with the existing version and ended up creating new versions of the composite. Before deploying the new version, I un-deployed the old versions. However the old versions still seem to be running in the background and picking up the files from source folder. Does anyone know how if there are any additional steps to wipe out the older versions completely in-addition to un-deploying from EM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are no additional steps required after undeploying from EM.